# How can I access a data file my application has saved?

Tags: android, windows, export

I have an prototype Android Application I'm developing. It saves my own debugging data to a file on the phone.

What's the simplest way to get this file off the phone and onto my Windows machine so I can examine it for debugging purposes ?

Comment: Where do you save it? SD-card/external memory? Or in your apps internal directory?

Comment: save the file somewhere at /mnt/sdcard - it will be visible from the eclipse file explorer and when you put your phone in USB Storage mode

Comment: I use Ansca Corona to develop the app, which lets me save to the "documents directory" which I assume is on the phone somewhere

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse there is something called 'File Explorer'

```
Window -> Show view -> Others -> Android -> File Explorer
```

There you have the option to download or upload files to the device.

Comment: The same thing can also be accessed outside eclipse. Launch the `ddms` app from your `ANDROID_SDK\tools` directory, select a device and click `Device -> File explorer`.

Comment: Hi, I use Ansca Corona to develop with, which doesn't have this feature. Can I use Eclipse to provide this functionality even though I've built the application with Ansca Corona ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the phone is on wifi, there are a number of Samba apps and modules, including the ASTRO SMB MOdule for ASTRO File Manager. These will create a "Windows" style file server on your network. You would need to set up the share in the SMB app for the log file destination.

Comment: Yes, the phone IS on wifi. I already use ASTRO FILE MANAGER. I'll have a look at the SMB module. Will it allow access to the application's data folder on the phone ? That's the only location I can save the file to?